# Load array from PHP via jQuery.ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

OK, so I want to get a row of data from a DB via `jQuery.ajax()`

Here is the code where I want to load it:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'mypage.php?id=345',
  success: function(data) {
    //process array of data
  }
});
```

Here is the code on the page that jQuery is loading from:

```
$DBH = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

$STH = $DBH->("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = :id");    

$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$data = array( 'id' => $_GET['id']);  
$returnArray = $STH->fetch($data);

// How do I return $returnArray as an Array to jquery?
```

Not sure what to do to return the array. I guess I can `implode()` it as a string and then `split()` once returned but I thought there might be a better way.

Also, I am new to using `PDO` so if I did it wrong please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) - you can read that in Javascript natively.

Comment: will also need to specify dataType: 'json', in the `$.ajax()` call or send back a JSON mime-type, in order that jquery will read the response correctly

Comment: @Tom I used $.getJSON instead of $.ajax

Comment: @John Isaacks: ah ok. it was just the example used $.ajax().

Comment: @Tom right, I originally planned to use $.ajax but did a google search on jquery json after reading this answer and found the getJSON method. But thanks for the comment, it can save someone a headache!

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
$testArray=array('a'=>array('b','c'));
print Zend_Json::encode($testArray);
```